# IPFIX vlanId element in access switchports

Tags: vlan, switchport, ipfix

According to IANA definition, IPFIX elementId 58 `vlanId` is:

> Virtual LAN identifier **associated with ingress interface**. For dot1q
> vlans, see 243 dot1qVlanId.

But according to RFC5102:

> Description:
> The IEEE 802.1Q VLAN identifier (VID) **extracted from the Tag
> Control Information field that was attached to the IP packet**.

I didn't find any updates to this element in RFC6313 and RFC7012. So what should this element be for packets coming from an access switchport? The original IP packets have no VLAN Tag, but the ingress port definitely has an associated pvid.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no explicit VLAN tag (802.1Q), vlanId is the VLAN ID associated with an untagged frame for the ingress port.